# Angular router link How to pass json into <a ... [queryParams]="q=|JSON|"/>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

From the view of an angular i'd like to fill a query param with a json object.

```html
<ngx-datatable-column name="Sku" prop="product.sku" [flexGrow]="0.5">
  <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
    <a [routerLink]="['/general','products']" [queryParams]="{q: { search: value } }">
      {{value}}
    </a>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Unfortunately, the above code produces the following link:
`http://localhost:4200/general/products?q=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Instead of `http://localhost:4200/general/products?q={"search": "SomeSearchValue"}`. (html escape ofc.)

How could i make this work?

EDIT:

`<a [routerLink]="['/general','products']" [queryParams]="{q: { search: value }.toString() }">`

Does not work.

Comment: i don't think you can put objects in query params, use  a key value instead

Comment: You are getting object Object, so something is wrong

Comment: @mak15 thats the way the rest of the app is setup so i cannot change that - i also feel like it should be possible somehow to convert the json object to a string and pass that in isntead, but i'm not sure how to apporach that from the view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, its the json pipe:

```html
    <a [routerLink]="['/general','products']" [queryParams]="{q: { search: value } | json }">
      {{value}}
    </a>
```

Comment: But what about thar first q?

Answer (score 0):

What is it the firts q?

Try this:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Sku" prop="product.sku" [flexGrow]="0.5">
  <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
    <a [routerLink]="['/general','products']" [queryParams]="{ search: value }">
      {{value}}
    </a>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```